# Android in-app Billing with multiple users on one device

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an application which supports in-app billing. However a user can login to this app using multiple accounts or he can even register a new account.

Can I somehow use in-app billing, so that the purchases would be linked not to the google id, but exactly to the account which made the purchase.

For example:

1. User downloads the app to his phone and does the actions described below only on this device.
2. User logins using 123@gmail.com account.
3. He purchases subscription1 and proceeds with the payment.
4. He logs out.
5. Now he logins using 456@gmail.com account.
6. He can also purchase subscription1, as 456@gmail.com never purchased it. So he purchases subscription1 one more time.
7. He logs out.
8. Now both 123@gmail.com and 456@gmail.com accounts own this subscription.
9. Profit.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan nope, that's why the whole idea of purchases was reworked in that app

Comment: would be helpful if u provide the details of such rework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-app-billing works through google services and all purchases will be verified for a current user. Starting from Android 4.2 you can create multiple user profiles on one device and in-app-billing will work as you described.

You may just log out/in but it takes time to synchronize some information and you may experience some glitches.

Comment: Is it true in case it signs in using Google account only or does it work even when the user logs in anew using some other email and password?